# How to handle and generate big files in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, download

I am quite new in the rails world, and today I faced the following problem:

I have to generate a really big json. At first I tried to do it in memory but there wasn't enough so I generated a file and stored all the rows there. Now I have to download this file from a client. How can I do this with rails?

Am I using the best approach? I read in some blogs that they recommend to use Amazon S3.

Any Ideas??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully *understand your problem* but I will try to give you some tips:

If the file generation is taking long time (is cpu intensive) you might want to look at queuing.

These are techniques which "allow you to create jobs and place them on a queue, then, later, pull those jobs off the queue and process them." So your ruby/rails process can still serve incoming requests while the file generation is put on a queue.

- https://github.com/defunkt/resque

S3 is a storage option from Amazon, something like an external hardrive for the web. It is useful for storing big chunks of data like images or your json files.

So S3 will only help you if you need to store your big json files online.

Again: I'm not sure where exactly your problem is but I had the impression you were a little confused I hope this helps.